# Why is file sharing missing from sharing preferences?

Tags: macos, sharing

File sharing is not an option for me under 'sharing'.

[image]

The image above illustrates the lack of file sharing, but I do have the following items:

- dvd or cd sharing
- screen sharing
- scanner sharing
- remote login
- remote management
- remote apple events
- bluetooth sharing

Any idea why certain macs have different items in the sharing pane?

Comment: You're also missing Printer Sharing, Web Sharing, Xgrid Sharing, and Internet Sharing.

Comment: Is this a corporate or school-owned computer? If so, my guess would be that someone has disabled these functions for security purposes.

Comment: what type is your account? Admin? Regular user? Restricted one? /btw, welcome here :)/